# Data usable everywhere on Angular

Tags: angular, components

I would like to use some datas everywhere on my angular app.

I try to use a service to do that, but it don't work.

My first component

```
import { RestApiService } from '../../shared/services/restapi.service';



export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

 .
 .
 .
constructor(public restApi: RestApiService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.loadInfo();
}

loadInfo() {
  return this.restApi.getInfos().subscribe((data: {}) => {
    this.restApi.MyInfos = data;
  })
  
}
```

I Try to import it and share it with a Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse, HttpParams  } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

import { dataResponse } from '../models/dataResponse';
.
.
.
export class RestApiService {
MyInfos: any = [];

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    })
  }

  getInfos(): Observable<dataResponse> {
     return this.http.post<dataResponse>(this.apiURL + '/getInfos/', this.httpOptions)
  }
```

I would like to use it on the sidebar, header and all my components

My second composant

```
import { RestApiService } from '../../shared/services/restapi.service';



export class MysecondComponent implements OnInit {
infos: any = [];
 .
 .
 .
constructor(public restApi: RestApiService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.loadInfo();
}

loadInfo() {
  this.infos = this.restApi.MyInfos;
  
}
```

I tried many syntax to use it, but It don't work.

Could you help me please ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: did you decorate the `RestApiService` class with `@Injectable` decorator?

Comment: Yes I did it @MehdiShakeri

Comment: where you provide your service? did you encounter with `NullInjector` error?

Comment: "apiUrl" is my link to my server, my request is ok. when I use it with an array on the component it's run correctly.I have no erreur

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use a subject instead of loading it once and then spreading that subject through out the app.

```
@Injectable()
export class RestApiService {
  public infos$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    })
  }

  loadInfo(){
     this.http.post<dataResponse>(this.apiURL + '/getInfos/', this.httpOptions)
              .subscribe((result) => this.infos$.next(result));
  }
}
```

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
        constructor(public restApi: RestApiService) {}   
        ngOnInit() {
          this.restApi.loadInfo();
        }
    }
```

```
export class MysecondComponent implements OnInit {
    infos: Observable<any> = restApi.infos$;
    constructor(private restApi: RestApiService) {}
}
```

This way you wont have timing problems and the detection of changes is not related to the angular change detection cycle.

Comment: hello @misha130 ... I ha juste change this: infos: Observable<any> = restApi.infos$;  to this.restApi.infos$ ....... I try it ... in my component.html I try to get ma data ... <div class="list-group" *ngIf="Infos.length !== 0">{{nfos.data.name}}  ... I have this error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined ... Have got an idea ?